# Configuration of django-ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

I playing around with django-ckeditor and I have a few questions:
My configuration in django settings.py is:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
    'toolbar': 'full',
    'height': 300,
    'width': 800,
   }, 
}
```

1) What do I have to change in the settings to get an inline-editor (the toolbar only appears if I click into the textarea)?

2) Right now height is set to 300px. If I write more text I get vertical scrollbars. Is there a way to avoid scrollbars and make an auto resize of the editor (means the height of the editor increases with every new line I put in)?